# Console application code to MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC. Can someone tell me how can I write the below code in MVC.

```
if (this.txtInput.Text.Trim() != String.Empty && !this.txtInput.Text.EndsWith(";"))
{
    this.txtInput.Text += ";";
}

string[] sadObjects = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(this.txtInput.Text).Split(';');

this.txtInput.Text += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ado.Name) + "; ";
```

Comment: I'm assuming your original code is from a WebForms/WinForms application? MVC doesn't work like that. A comprehensive answer would be too long to formulate here. There is plenty of documentation online where you can learn about MVC. You can start here: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views

Answer (score 0):

[Andrei Olariu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3819485/andrei-olariu) is absolutely right,in MVC you can't access `this`. You will have to pass the current element values to the controller through javascript or jquery. Then you can do all the operations the same way on the controller function parameter.

```
Public ActionResult FuncA(string myvalue){
if (myvalue.Trim() != String.Empty && !myvalue.EndsWith(";"))
{
    myvalue += ";";
}
string[] sadObjects = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myvalue).Split(';');
myvalue += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ado.Name) + "; ";
}
```